# custom path animation with CSS

Tags: css, animation

```
@keyframes fadeOutDownMed {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(150px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(150px);
    transform: translateY(150px);
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/iaezzy/99JbQ/

This works but the animation is straight down, I need it to fade out slant like `\`, or to a certain element wherever that might be, is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe try animating `translateX` at the same time?

Comment: If you need the element to move relative to another then obviously it would make sense to position the two together and keyframe the position values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try append `translateX` to the `transform` attribute like this:

```
@keyframes fadeOutDownMed {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0) translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0) translateX(0);
    transform: translateY(0) translateX(0);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(150px) translateX(150);
    -ms-transform: translateY(150px) translateX(150);
    transform: translateY(150px) translateX(150);
  }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/k7Wp4/